# Segmentation fault when inserting new integer into dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management, segmentation-fault

Getting segmentation fault with my dynamic array when I am trying to insert new integer into it.

```
void function1()
{
    ...
    string * array1 = new string[array_length];
    function2(array1, array_length);
    ...
    delete [] array1;
}

void function2(string *array_frm_function1, int &array_length_frm_function1)
{
    int * new_array = new int[array_length_frm_function1];
    int new_array_pos;

    for(int i = 0; i < array_length_frm_function1; i++)
    {
        string subtracted_string = array_frm_function1[i].substr(1,1); // sample string - [3,3]-543-McDonalds, will return '3'
        int string_to_integer = stoi(substracted_string);
        new_array[new_array_pos++] = string_to_integer;
    }
}
```

The goal is to extract the first value from the string, in the above example '3' and turn it into an int datatype then store it inside the dynamic array.

When I cout the variables memory address (array_frm_function1, subtracted_string, string_to_integer), they are all different. Wouldn't the variable string_to_integer works this the memory address are different?

I do not know what is causing this as the error just says it is segmentation fault. What is the issue with my functions above in regards to the memory address allocation and what should be the solution to get rid of this error?

Note: I can't use vector in this case! Many thanks!

Comment: `function2` leaks memory.  -- *Note: I can't use vector in this case!* -- And why not?  I guess it's more important to teach how to leak memory than to use `std::vector`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the school want us to learn the hard code way. Will changing * to *& resolve the memory leak issue? Not too sure which part of it leak.

Comment: *the school want us to learn the hard code way* -- This is exactly why many new programmers drop using C++, and instead take up other languages such as Python, Java, etc.  With those other languages, the curriculum doesn't go through that nonsense of having students go through the hard way of implementing their programs.  Your function leaks memory, is hard to use correctly, and other issues that have to be addressed before it is even considered to be useful. A `std::vector` on the other hand is bug-free, does the same thing, and is ready to use right-out-of-the-box.

Comment: You allocate `new_array` locally, do stuff, and just leave the function.  That is a defacto memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough

```
int new_array_pos;
```

should be

```
int new_array_pos = 0;
```

You should initialise variables before you use them, and you should pay attention to the compiler that warns you when you aren't doing that.

Comment: Wow,  thanks for pointing it out! I must have overlooked it when I copy and paste this from another function of mine and did some mistake when I was editing the new function. Silly me! Thanks for being my rubber duck here. T_T

Comment: @user3118602 it is a good habit to have all local variables initialized on declaration. But all your code is precisely designed to have memory leaks and errors.